# How can I display error messages in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

As I can put an error message to the user when it completes the fields of my form, I am using views based on classes `CreateView` .. and I only found success_message

```
class RegistroUsuario(CreateView):
model = User
template_name = "usuario/registrar.html"
form_class = RegistroForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('denuncias:index')
permission_denied_message = "You must login to contact the administrator"
```

I also tried to add this function but it no longer creates the regitros when I use it

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    response = super(RegistroUsuario, self).form_invalid(form)
    messages.error(
        self.request, 'Error de validacion: Email o contraseñas incorrectas, recuerde las contraseñas deben tener un minimo de 8 caracteres con letras y numeros')
    return response
```

Comment: Your form is responsible for any error messages due to validation failures.

Answer (score 0):

After filling registrar form redirect submit button to other URL showing register successful or not successful.
[Like it is done in this for invalid_login.html](https://github.com/vineetjai/hibbert-django/blob/master/templates/)